# Is there a more readable/efficient way of doing this?

Tags: python

I have a bot that process some metadata from a replay file (it reads the binary) I then parse out all the variables I require.

Basically due to the game dev the files can be a bit confusing so I've written some code to ascertain the correct result I need (Basically appending player names to a list that is then pumped into an embed).

I'm curious to know if there is a much more efficient or readable way of doing what I have got working with this logic. I've covered all the eventualities from the metadata, it just looks god awful.

```
        if ownervictory < 3:
            for player in playersdata:
                if len(playersdata) == 2:
                    if owneralliance == int(player['PlayerAlliance']):
                        loserlist.append(player)
                    else:
                        winnerlist.append(player)
                elif len(playersdata) == 4:
                    replayPlayer = 0
                    if owneralliance == 2 or owneralliance == 3:
                        replayPlayer = 1
                    if replayPlayer == int(player['PlayerAlliance']):
                        loserlist.append(player)
                    else:
                        winnerlist.append(player)
                elif len(playersdata) == 6:
                    replayPlayer = 0
                    if owneralliance == 3 or owneralliance == 4:
                        replayPlayer = 1
                    if replayPlayer == int(player['PlayerAlliance']):
                        loserlist.append(player)
                    else:
                        winnerlist.append(player)
                elif len(playersdata) == 8:
                    replayPlayer = 0
                    if owneralliance == 4 or owneralliance == 5 or owneralliance == 6 or owneralliance == 7:
                        replayPlayer = 1
                    if replayPlayer == int(player['PlayerAlliance']):
                        loserlist.append(player)
                    else:
                        winnerlist.append(player)
        elif ownervictory >= 3:
            for player in playersdata:
                if len(playersdata) == 2:
                    if owneralliance != int(player['PlayerAlliance']):
                        loserlist.append(player)
                    else:
                        winnerlist.append(player)
                elif len(playersdata) == 4:
                    replayPlayer = 0
                    if owneralliance == 2 or owneralliance == 3:
                        replayPlayer = 1
                    if replayPlayer != int(player['PlayerAlliance']):
                        loserlist.append(player)
                    else:
                        winnerlist.append(player)
                elif len(playersdata) == 6:
                    replayPlayer = 0
                    if owneralliance == 3 or owneralliance == 4 or owneralliance == 4:
                        replayPlayer = 1
                    if replayPlayer != int(player['PlayerAlliance']):
                        loserlist.append(player)
                    else:
                        winnerlist.append(player)
                elif len(playersdata) == 8:
                    replayPlayer = 0
                    if owneralliance == 4 or owneralliance == 5 or owneralliance == 6 or owneralliance == 7:
                        replayPlayer = 1
                    if replayPlayer != int(player['PlayerAlliance']):
                        loserlist.append(player)
                    else:
                        winnerlist.append(player)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code was very repetitive, with only small modifications between branches. Thus you can refactor the code by using functions, and alternating the arguments instead of code duplication. I've come up with this version, although I can't run it without your data and other code, so let's just hope I didn't break the logic anywhere

```
# ============ example input data ===============
loserlist = []
winnerlist = []

owneralliance = 2
ownervictory = 3
playersdata = [{'PlayerAlliance': 1}, {'PlayerAlliance': 2}, {'PlayerAlliance': 3}, {'PlayerAlliance': 4}]
# ===============================================

def append_winlose_list(player, testPlayer, testPassedList, testFailedList):
    if testPlayer == int(player['PlayerAlliance']):
        testPassedList.append(player)
    else:
        testFailedList.append(player)

if ownervictory < 3:
    testPassedList = loserlist
    testFailedList = winnerlist
else:
    testPassedList = winnerlist
    testFailedList = loserlist
    
for player in playersdata:
    if len(playersdata) == 2:
        testPlayer = owneralliance
    elif len(playersdata) == 4:
        testPlayer = 1 if owneralliance in [2, 3] else 0
    elif len(playersdata) == 6:
        testPlayer = 1 if owneralliance in [3, 4] else 0
    elif len(playersdata) == 8:
        testPlayer = 1 if owneralliance in [4, 5, 6, 7] else 0
    append_winlose_list(player, testPlayer, testPassedList, testFailedList)

print('Winners', winnerlist)
print('Losers', loserlist)
```

Comment: Thank You Alexey, works like a charm. I figured it could be refactored, I kind of got it working by just doing the logic in my head. Needed to get a bit more creative with the code. I will learn from this knowledge - thank you.